# VBA Macro worksheet_change does not work properly

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with properly functioning macro. I wrote a short and simple code to either hide or unhide two last columns, depending on the selected month.

Month selection is possible with a combo box. Each month has assigned a number to it (1 - January, 2 - February, ..., etc.). The number shows in cell A1 and it changes upon selection of a month.

I want my macro to run properly depending on the month number which I choose.

```cs
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
          Dim nr_kol As Long
          If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
            For nr_kol = 32 To 34
                If Month(Cells(6, nr_kol)) = Cells(1, 1) Then
                    Columns(nr_kol).Hidden = False
                Else
                    Columns(nr_kol).Hidden = True
                End If
            Next
        End If

    End Sub
```

EDIT(sorry, clicked submit too fast)

Cell A1 changes depending on combobox selection (box is located in a different row). What I have noticed is that columns will hide, but only if cell A1 is changed manually. But when I change the cell to month index containing 30 or 31 days, columns will remain hidden, thus I have two issues.

1. A1 cell needs to be changed manually (macro is not working whatsoever when change is made by a combobox selection)
2. When I make a manual change to February - two or three last columns will hide (as these are for the first two/three days of March). However, when I change the number to anything but February (2), columns are still hidden even though at least one should re-appear back again (if month contains 30 days).

Comment: Put your (adjusted) hiding code in the DropDown_Change not in the worksheet  change event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the below image and its explanation

[image]

1. Add a combobox
2. Row 1 will contain the Months in that format
3. Row 2 will contain the dates of the month, make sure that there is no empty cell between the dates

the code as below

```
Option Explicit
Dim monthsList(11) As String
Dim firstCell As Integer
Dim lastCell As Integer

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    Columns("A:XX").Hidden = False

    '0 to reset the columns
    If ComboBox1.Value = 0 Then Exit Sub

    'take the last month of the list
    Dim var1() As String
    var1 = Split(monthsList(11), "~")

    firstCell = 4 'assuming that the start of the date begins from column 4
    lastCell = Val(var1(2))

    Range(Cells(firstCell, firstCell), Cells(firstCell, lastCell)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True

    Erase var1

    var1 = Split(monthsList(ComboBox1.Value - 1), "~")

    firstCell = Val(var1(1))
    lastCell = Val(var1(2))

    'display only current selected month
    Range(Cells(firstCell, firstCell), Cells(firstCell, lastCell)).EntireColumn.Hidden = False

End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    Erase monthsList

    'unhide any columns or write a macro that recognises the hidden columns and keeps it hidden
    Columns("A:XX").Hidden = False
    Dim i As Integer
    ComboBox1.Clear
    For i = 0 To 12
        ComboBox1.AddItem i
    Next

    '0 added to display all the sheets

    ComboBox1.Select (1)

    'let this be the start of the date range
    'select the cell in the second row
    Range("D2").Select

    'go to the last date
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select

    'go to the first row
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select

    lastCell = ActiveCell.Column
    'select the last month
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select

    For i = 12 To 1 Step -1
                            'cell value             start date of the month     last date of the month
        monthsList(i - 1) = ActiveCell.Value & "~" & ActiveCell.Column & "~" & lastCell
        lastCell = ActiveCell.Column - 1
        Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Next

End Sub
```

Please note that you need to make the necessary changes as needed

I hope that this resolves your pain

Please mark it as an answer